# Twitter API - Delete tweet with unique ID after posting

Tags: c#, twitter, automation

C#

Hello Guys,

I have a question regarding deleting a tweet via API. So, how to put a unique tweet id after POST to DELETE request?
I do not know how to take it from Post response and put in DELETE path /statuses/destroy/:id.json instead of :id.json.
Please advise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apart from the obvious why do care, it's just Twitter? Do you mean, when you create a post to Twitter you can't delete it in a subsequent call using the result?

Comment: Exactly, I am working on my API Automation Framework for my portfolio and I need to automate this scenario, but I do not know how to do that with unique id which is different for each post

Comment: Maybe you can provide some examples.

Comment: @TheGeneral once I send a POST request to create a tweet I am getting a response with Content type string, so in this string, it contains Id: {unique_id} of the created tweet, and int this case I need to take this unique id and put into POST which will delete created tweet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Hanna how did you solve this?

Comment: added Delete method and put it in POST method in the test

' public IRestResponse PostTweet(string message)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("1.1/statuses/update.json", Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter("status", message, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            return GetResponse(request);
        }

        public IRestResponse DeleteTweet(ulong id)
        { 
            var request = new RestRequest("1.1/statuses/destroy/{:id}.json", Method.POST);
            request.AddUrlSegment(":id", id);
            return GetResponse(request);
        }
'